# No Value given for one or more required Parameters in Update Statement C# Microsoft Access

Tags: c#, ms-access, windows

I keep getting this error and checked many times to make sure if everything is correct.I think I am doing everything is correct. Not sure where the issue is. If any one can help me with this would be greatly appreciated.

_query = string.Format("UPDATE tblFormOQ SET UINumWorkers1 = {0},UINumWorkers2 = {1}, UINumWorkers3 = {2}, UISubjectWages = {3}, UIExcessWages= {4}, UITaxRate = {5},  UIPrepaid = {6}, UIPenalty = {7}, SWTSubjectWages = {8}, SWTax = {9}, SWTPrepaid = {10}, SWTMonth1 = {11}, SWTMonth2 = {12}, SWTMonth3 = {13}, TriMetSubjectWages = {14},  TriMetPrepaid = {15}, LaneSubjectWages = {16}, LanePrepaid = {17},  WCHours = {18}, WCPrepaid = {19}  WHERE BusinessID = '{20}' and Year = '{21}' and  Quarter = {22}", _UINumWorkers1, _UINumWorkers2, _UINumWorkers3, _UISubjectWages, _UIExcessWages, _UITaxRate, _UIPrepaid, _UIPenalty, _SWTSubjectWages, _SWTax, _SWTPrepaid, _SWTMonth1, _SWTMonth2, _SWTMonth3, _TriMetSubjectWages,_TriMetPrepaid, _LaneSubjectWages, _LanePrepaid, _WCHours, _WCPrepaid,  _Businessid, _Year, _Quarter);

Comment: What part of that question looks even *remotely* readable to you?  Also note that your `catch` block is not only unnecessary, it's actually *damaging*.  It throws away useful debugging information.  If all you want to do is throw the exception, then remove the `catch` block entirely and just let the exception be thrown.

Comment: Consider fixing your formatting

Comment: Hi David, I just updated the code, I have removed Catch Block, I kept it just for handy message. That is is good advice. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

First, `Year` is a reserved word in Access SQL so you need to enclose it in square brackets in order to use it as a column name.

Also, you are using "dynamic SQL" to build your command, so it can break if your data contains special characters (or if you have forgotten delimiters, as seems to be the case here). You really should be using a *parameterized query*, something like this

```cs
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tblFormOQ SET UINumWorkers1 = ?,UINumWorkers2 = ?, UINumWorkers3 = ?, UISubjectWages = ?, UIExcessWages= ?, UITaxRate = ?, UIPrepaid = ?, UIPenalty = ?, SWTSubjectWages = ?, SWTax = ?, SWTPrepaid = ?, SWTMonth1 = ?, SWTMonth2 = ?, SWTMonth3 = ?, TriMetSubjectWages = ?, TriMetPrepaid = ?, LaneSubjectWages = ?, LanePrepaid = ?, WCHours = ?, WCPrepaid = ? WHERE BusinessID = ? and [Year] = ? and Quarter = ?";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", _UINumWorkers1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", _UINumWorkers2);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", _UINumWorkers3);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", _UISubjectWages);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", _UIExcessWages);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", _UITaxRate);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", _UIPrepaid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", _UIPenalty);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", _SWTSubjectWages);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", _SWTax);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", _SWTPrepaid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", _SWTMonth1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", _SWTMonth2);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", _SWTMonth3);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", _TriMetSubjectWages);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", _TriMetPrepaid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", _LaneSubjectWages);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", _LanePrepaid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", _WCHours);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", _WCPrepaid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", _Businessid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", _Year);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", _Quarter);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Hi Gord, Thank you for your response. Very helpful. I actually have 6 forms, I have been using the same approach for saving, all of them are working fine except the one which i posted. But, your approach gave me the field which was having the problems saving with (_SWTax). I think I should adopt your approach which is more efficient than mine. Thank you very much!!